# Creating temporary file and rename to actual file

Tags: java, io

I am trying to create a temporary file and then rename it to a usable file. The temp file is getting created in %temp% but not getting renamed:-

```
    static void writeFile() {
    try {
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile("TEMP_FAILED_MASTER", "");

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(tempFile);
        for (String record : new String[] {"a","b"}) {
            pw.println(record);
        }
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        System.out.println(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());

        File errFile = new File("C:/bar.txt");
        tempFile.renameTo(errFile);
        System.out.println(errFile.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("Check!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: it's working for me....

Comment: If it's not working, then the `renameTo(errFile)` will likely be returning false, if you set it to a local variable and print it out to see. If this is the case then it's likely you have chosen an invalid path.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons why a rename can fail.  The common ones are:

- You don't have write permission for the source or destination directory.
- The file you are renaming is open (on Windows)
- You are attempting to rename across different file systems.

It can be difficult to diagnose these (and other) failure reasons if you are using `File.renameTo` because all you get is a boolean return value.

I recommend using `Files.move` instead.  It can cope with moving files between file systems, and will throw an exception if the file cannot be renamed.